# How to modify values in html string?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

In my extension, I am replicating HTML content of a webpage using `$.html()`. However, doing so loses some values such as `<select>` elements. To solve this problem, I gave a unique id to each element of the webpage, then got the HTML content and in that HTML content, I tried to set the values correctly. However, that did not work. Here is the code snippet:

```
$( function() 
{ 
    $('*').each( function(i) 
    { 
        $(this).attr('uid', i);
    }); 
});

var html_data = $("html").html();
$("option:selected", html_data).removeAttr("selected");
var all_selected = $("option:selected");
for (var i = 0; i < all_selected.length; i++) 
{
    var uid = $(all_selected[i]).attr("uid");
    $("[uid="+uid+"]", html_data).attr("selected", true)
}
```

Problem is, when I execute "`$("option:selected", html_data).removeAttr("selected");`", it does return elements with "selected" removed, but original html_data remains unchanged. It seems that html_data is read-only. I also tried to replace those tags with returned tags from `.removeAttr("selected")`. However, that did not work either.

Is there solution to this?

UPDATE: From the first answer, there seems to be some confusion. Let me try to clarify it:

- I can't change the "selected" value directly on the webpage.
- I want to get entire webpage and send it to my backend controlling page (background.js).
- However, when I get the entire webpage using .html() to send it to backend, selected values are lost.

Comment: Do you *really* need to serialize the whole page? That sounds unnecessary. And it's unreliable, because the value of input fields, including `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` is not copied.

Comment: Yes I do want to copy the whole page so that I can analyze it at the backend. For security reasons, I wan't the information flow to be only one directional - from content-script (included in each webpage to background servers). And I know its unreliable, that is why I am asking if there is any way to make it reliable. Instead, I am getting down voted and voted for closing!!

Comment: You could clone the document, loop through all input fields and mirror its value to the cloned document, then serialize it. PS. These were not my votes, calm down.

Comment: You are right. A temporary hackish fix that I implemented for "select" element was to delete default selected options for original document, then set the currently selected options as default in the loaded webpage and THEN making a copy of the document. I will repeat this process for other HTML elements as I will face the problem. And sorry I was not frustrated at you but SO in general that a genuine question was getting downvoted w/o even telling me what is wrong with it so that I could have clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this.

Content script side code:

```
//First, generate a unique id for each element                                                                  
$(function() { $('*').each(function(i) { $(this).attr('my_uid', i);}); });

//Once you send the page to the backend, all information such as whether the 
//element is rendered or not is lost. To retain that, add one more attribute to 
//each element                                                          
$(function() {
       $('*').each(function(i) {
         if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
              $(this).attr('final_rendering', "visible");
         }
         else {
              $(this).attr('final_rendering', "hidden");
         }
  });
});

//Collect all values that are lost in an object                  
var my_vals = {};
var input_elements = $(":input[type='text'], select");

for (var i = 0; i < input_elements.length; i++) {
     var uid = $(input_elements[i]).attr("my_uid");
     var val = $('[my_uid='+ uid +']').val();
     my_vals[uid] = val;
}

var html_page = $("html").html();
send_response({
    'html_page' : html_page,
    'my_vals'  :  my_vals
});
```

Background script code:

```
function get_html_page_cb(ret_val) {

   var html_page = ret_val['html_page'];
   var my_vals = ret_val['my_vals'];
   var html_doc_copy = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("webpage");
   html_doc_copy.documentElement.innerHTML = html_page;

   for (var id in my_vals) {
      $("[my_uid="+id+"]",html_doc_copy).val(my_vals[id]);
   }
}
```

If anyone has a better idea, I am all ears.